# best way to send a variable along with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-views

I am reading a djangobook and get questions about `HttpResponseRedirect` and `render_to_response`.

suppose I have a contact form, which posts data to confirm view. It goes through all the validation and database stuff. Then, as a usual way, I output the html with

```
return render_to_response('thank_you.html',
                          dict(user_code = user_code),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, the book suggested "You should always issue a redirect for successful `POST` requests." because if the user "Refresh" on a this page, the request will be repeated. I wonder what's the best way to send the user_code along through `HttpResponseRedirect` to the `thank_you.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the information in a query string:

```
thank_you/?user_code=1234
```

Or use a session variable.

The problem with a query string is that the user can see the data.

Answer (score 0):

When you [send a redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect), you are sending the user back a response ([a 302 HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)) and they are then making an entirely new request to the provided URL. That's a completely new request/response cycle so there is no way to supply data unless you save it in a session variable, cache, cookie etc.

What you can do instead of telling the user to redirect, is to call the view you want to show them yourself from within the same request (i.e. at the point you would issue the redirect) and then you could pass whatever you liked.